# PHP script to find Apple Touch Icon

Tags: php, get

I have a PHP script that crawls a page and extracts the first image in the page, this isn't working too well, and I'd rather get no results than a completely ambiguous picture, so is it possible to modify the following script to extract the universal URL of the first `link rel="apple-touch-icon"` or `link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"`?

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['url']!='')
{
function get($a,$b,$c)
{ // Gets a string between 2 strings
$y = explode($b,$a);
$x = explode($c,$y[1]);
return $x[0];
}
$url=get_meta_tags("".$_REQUEST['url'].""); 
?>

<div class="addSitetitle"><?php echo get(file_get_contents(''.$_REQUEST['url'].''), "<title>", "</title"); ?></div>
<div class="addSitedescription"><?php echo ($url["description"]); ?></div>
<div class="addSitekeywords"><?php echo ($url["keywords"]); ?></div>
<div class="addSitecopyright"><?php echo ($url["copyright"]); ?></div>
<div class="addSiteimage"><img <?php echo get(file_get_contents(''.$_REQUEST['url'].''), "<img", "/>"); ?> /></div>
```

Edited to include get function.

Comment: have fun *post* processing HTML with Hypertext *Pre* Processor, have you tried `javascript`?

Comment: Hey Alex, look, to be honest, it's all working flawlessly in my deployment, I'm just ending up with irrelevant images. If anyone knows how to modify the snippet, that's great.

Comment: we need to see code of the function `get()`

Comment: `function get($a,$b,$c)` .. have you ever heard about descriptive variable names?

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @verbumSapienti SimpleHtmlDom is for php4. (10 years ago) Note that today there is `DOMDocument::loadHtml()`. Its part of the PHP core. No external libraries required.

Comment: I was hoping for a quick, constructive answer. Sorry guys, thought this was stackoverflow.com

Comment: Source: [link](http://www.webinfopedia.com/extract-meta-data-from-url-using-php.html)

Comment: @hek2mgl latest version 10/10/2012 but thanks for the alternative.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your input hek2mgl, it may not be constructive, but I can see that you're very passionate. Good on you mate.

Comment: Yeah I am. But don't thake it personal. This is because I'm often in real life the guy which can fix such code using variables like `$a`, `$b`, `$b2`, `$tmp`.... (mostly without comments).. If I can give you a good advice, learn about the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class and the usage of [`XPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you can obtain links to the images with code such as:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$img = $html->find('img[rel=apple-touch-icon]');
echo $img->href;
```

Comment: note that your simplhtmldom stuff is for PHP4. PHP5 `hasDOMDocument::loadHTML()`. Please wake up. I've told you this in comments

Comment: that doesn't invalidate my answer and is non-constructive. don't be a fool.

Comment: I think there is no good reason for an external dependency, if the language core supports this (much faster). Use `DOMDocument::loadHtml()` to create a DOM document and `DOMXPath` for queries. However, now you know

Comment: This doesnt work for me. I tried using foreach($html->find('img[rel=apple-touch-icon]') as $element) { echo $element->href . '<br>'; } instead and that doesnt work either.